# Intellij (Android Studio) javadoc folding

Tags: android-studio

I was wondering if I can configure Android Studio to do smart code folding on javadoc like it does with one liners.

E.g. I have:

```
/**
* Constructor
*/
public Players() {
    createPlayers();
}
```

I would like to see:

```
/** Constructor */
public Players() {
    createPlayers();
}
```

Folding just gives me:

```
/**...*/
public Players() {
    createPlayers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no options to customize this behaviour.

Code Folding options are available via:

```
File -> Settings ... Editor -> General -> Code Folding
```

While these options enable enabling and disabling certain types of constructs to be folded, they do not allow configuration for how the folded code appears.